# sending reply to user message

Tags: laravel, email

how can i send a reply on a specific message sent by a user?
I am using this code, but it send a message to  the user email not reply on user message

```
 $to_name = 'xx';
            $to_email = 'xx@gmail.com';
            $data = array('name' => "xx", "body" => "Test mail");
            Mail::send('mails.TestMail', $data, function ($message) use ($to_name, $to_email) {
                $message->to($to_email, $to_name)
                ->subject('Testing Mail');
                $message->from('xx@yy.com', 'test reply');

                if (count(Mail::failures()) > 0) {
                    echo("Error! Email did not send.");
                }
                echo 'sucess';
```

Comment: this sends message. it dosenot receive any to make a reply

Comment: ok, i can recieve message from email, maybe i haven't good knowledge about this.

Comment: when a customer send a message to my email, i would to reply to its message,that's what i need please

Comment: when i recieve message i can get its message-id but i don't know what have to do after that